# How can I find matching elements in an array using CouchDB's Mango selector?

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql, couchdb

How can I find selected only elements included value during array elements using CouchDB's Mango API?

I tried $elemMatch, but I didn't get the result I wanted

Document

```
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "user_info": [
        {
          "name": "kk",
          "age": "17",
        },
        {
          "name": "jj",
          "age": "21",
        },
        {
          "name": "kk",
          "age": "19",
        }
      ],
    }
```

my sql

```
{
        "selector": {
           "id": "id",
           "user_info": {
              "$elemMatch": {
                 "name": "kk"
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

now result :

```
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "user_info": [
        {
          "name": "kk",
          "age": "17",
        },
        {
          "name": "jj",
          "age": "21",
        },
        {
          "name": "kk",
          "age": "19",
        }
      ],
    }
```

But I want this result

```
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "user_info": [
        {
          "name": "kk",
          "age": "17",
        },
        {
          "name": "kk",
          "age": "19",
        }
      ],
    }
```

How can i get data I wanted?

I use CouchDB

I access CouchDB by go language

Comment: The query `selector` describes criteria used to select documents but it does not alter the documents. In order to obtain the desired result, you need to process the found documents and discard unwanted data from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you perform a query of this form:

```js
{
   "selector": {
      "user_info": {
         "$elemMatch": {
            "name": "kk"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You are asking the database for documents that have a `user_info` array which contains an object, one of whose's attributes is `name` with a value of `kk`.

This correctly returns the the whole documents that match this criteria.

If you want to extract a sub-set of the documents, you'll have to do that transformation in your client-side code once the database has returned the matching documents.

Comment: thanks, I solved the issue. I did to do that transformation in your client-side code once the database has returned the matching documents.